# 503 Errors on Images

Tags: php, database, image, database-connection, mediatemple

My site http://blackwagon.com recently started experiencing some database problems. On Monday 8/17 we noticed that no PHP or Java was loading. This led us to restore our site to a previous backup taken Sunday 8/16 with Media Temple. The backup restored and went into effect Tuesday 8/18, but all of our product images (http://blackwagon.com/shop/new-arrivals.html) are not showing and are instead returning 503 errors.

Upon further inspection, I'm seeing that it appears the images are missing from the folders they're supposed to be in, but even when I attempt to re-upload the image to the correct folder I get the same 503 error and broken image icon. The only way I've figured out how to get an image to display is to change the source patch entirely. This will work for a couple images here and there, but the bulk of our catalog is coded to refer to a specific image folder and it's not exactly possible to change it.

Our backend CMS is handled by a program called QubixCart and is no longer maintained. It's also incredibly PHP intensive and was coded in 2009 with no notation at all, so I'm having a hard time reverse engineering it.

Any ideas on how I can get my site back to normal? Anyone else experience 503 errors after restoring from a backup?

Comment: I would contact MediaTemple support if files that were supposed to be restored are missing.

Comment: I've been on and off the phone with them more times than I can count, and they haven't been much help. They've even given me the "we can't help because it's a content issue" line.

Comment: Broke down the paragraphs

Answer (score 0):

I worked on QubixCart in 2011. Because it's unmaintained, I recommend migrating your store to something like Shopify - possibly paying a contractor to do that migration for you. I'd be happy to help if you wanna get in touch.